# How to force break between inline-block divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, break

How can I force a break between inline-block divs that are currently in line?

```css
.sub-body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.start-container {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
}

.article-container-small {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    text-align: center;
}

.article-small {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 380px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.article-small-image-wrapper {
    height: 210px;
    width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.article-small-img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 210px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: transparent url('https://via.placeholder.com/400') center top no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}

.article-small-img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
      navigation is here
        </nav>
    <section class="sub-body"> <!-- this is where the fun begins... -->
            <div class="start-container">
                <div class="article-container-small">
        
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 001</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 002</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
                                <a href="#" target="inhalt"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 003</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
                                <a href="#" target="inhalt"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 004</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
                                <a href="#" target="inhalt"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 005</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(drastic cutout out of my actual project but i kept all the divs i use so you can see all the parent elements)

### What it looks like at the moment:

[image: what it looks like at the moment]

### What it should look like:

[image: what it should look like]

I know that i can select the nth child via:

```css
.article-small:nth-child(4n) {
}
```

But except for the background color or something like that I cannot alter the div.

for example when i try this:

```css
.article-small:nth-child(4n) {
    content: "\A"; 
    white-space: pre;
}
```

It does not do anything.

I tried it too with float: none; (does not alter the article anyway) and with display: block; (shredds the article's dimensions but does not force the wanted break).

What can I do to force a break after every nth article?

Comment: Is items count static? If so: wrap them inside another div in groups. Like Bootstrap has `.row` and inside `.col-*`

Comment: Well, i guess i have to correct myself here.

I use 

`code`
.article-small-img-001 {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 210px;
 width: 320px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background: transparent url('./images (web)/001.jpg') center top no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 transition: all 0.8s;
}

.article-small-img-001:hover {
 transform: scale(1.2);
}
`code`

for each article due to the fact that every article has its own background image... i guess there would be a way to work this out more professional, but i am a bloody starter.

Comment: usually you have one class for all, and then put background image in inline style when generating content

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
flex-wrap: wrap;          /* ADDED */
justify-content: center;  /* ADDED */
```

To class `article-container-small`. Final result should be as below:

```css
.article-container-small {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;          /* ADDED */
    justify-content: center;  /* ADDED */
}
```

The `flex-wrap: wrap` will break the line.
The `justify-content: center` will align them to the center.

Then you can add a margin-bottom or top if you want to give it more space. Modify `article-small` margin as: `margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;`

### DEMO

```css
.sub-body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.start-container {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
}

.article-container-small {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;          /* ADDED */
    justify-content: center;  /* ADDED */
}

.article-small {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 380px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px; /* MODIFIED */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.article-small-image-wrapper {
    height: 210px;
    width: 320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;           /* ADDED*/
}

.article-small-img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 210px;
    width: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background: transparent url('https://via.placeholder.com/400') center top no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: all 0.8s;
}

.article-small-img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
      navigation is here
        </nav>
    <section class="sub-body"> <!-- this is where the fun begins... -->
            <div class="start-container">
                <div class="article-container-small">
        
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 001</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 002</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
                                <a href="#" target="inhalt"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 003</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
                                <a href="#" target="inhalt"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 004</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
          
                    <div class="article-small">
                        <div class="article-small-image-wrapper">
                            <div class="article-small-img">
                                <a href="#" target="inhalt"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h2>Artikel 005</h2>
                        <br>
                        Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
                    </div>
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```